# CSS animation only works in chrome

Tags: css

CSS help
Can somone please tell me why this the background animation is only working for chrome?
Its not work on firefox or IE.

```
#animate-area {
    width: 100%;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    background-repeat: repeat;

    -webkit-animation: animatedBackground 10s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: animatedBackground 10s linear infinite;
    animation: animatedBackground 10s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatedBackground {
    from { background-position: 0 100%; }
    to { background-position: 0 0; }
}

@-moz-keyframes animatedBackground {
    from { background-position: 0 100%; }
    to { background-position: 0 0; }
}

@keyframes animatedBackground_m {
    from { background-position: 0 100%; }
    to { background-position: 0 0; }
}
```

Comment: For IE animation name is different `_m` extra added

Comment: CSS animations are a set of CSS3 properties, and they [aren't supported in all browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation) (yet?). I'd start there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have added below code in you css .. check the animation name here extra `_m` is added. this is the reason your animation is not working on IE and Firefox.

```
@keyframes animatedBackground_m {
    from { background-position: 0 100%; }
    to { background-position: 0 0; }
}
```

Check the working **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/qufaxuyi/5/edit)** here.

```
#animate-area {
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;

background:url("http://lorempixel.com/100/100/");
    -webkit-animation: animatedBackground 10s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: animatedBackground 10s linear infinite;
    animation: animatedBackground 10s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatedBackground {
    from { transform: rotate(0deg);
}
    to {  transform: rotate(360deg);
 }
}

@-moz-keyframes animatedBackground {
    from { transform: rotate(0deg);
}
    to {  transform: rotate(360deg);
 }
}

@keyframes animatedBackground {
    from { transform: rotate(0deg);
}
    to {  transform: rotate(360deg);
 }
}
```